# Kibana pie chart with slices for different frequency values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, pie-chart

I have an ES index where each document represents a user login. The document contains a "user_id" field (the other fields are not relevant).

I need to show a pie chart in kibana with the following slices:

- "1" with the number of users logged only once during the interval.
- "2" with the number of users logged twice during the interval.
- "3" with the number of users logged three times during the interval.
- ...
- "+10" with the number of users logged more than 10 times during the interval.

It's very easy to build a pie chart with a slice per user and the count of documents for that user. But that's not what I need. I'm a newbie in ElasticSearch and I don't even know if it's feasible to achieve this goal, or we need to have some preprocessing.

Thanks in advance,
Jaime